# How can I test an interactive function in emacs?

Tags: user-interface, testing, emacs

I'm the maintainer of [an Emacs package](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous) whose entire purpose is related to user interaction. Whenever I make a change to the code, I have to test it out manually to see if it works. It would be nice if I could do some automated testing, but I have no idea how to simulate user input in the way that would be required to do so. Is there any way to run an interactive function that will prompt the user and then respond to that prompt with simulated typing (including key combinations like C-j)?

Comment: Maybe you can do a kbd macro `C-x ( "some comands" C-x )` and edit it `C-x C-k RET `

Comment: My package doesn't actually provide a command, it provides an alternative to `completing-read`, so I can't test it by just running a command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New:** I have reimplemented my `with-simulated-input` macro using `execute-kbd-macro`, so it now *works in batch mode* as well. You can view the new implementation [here](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/with-simulated-input).

### Original answer:

I found the answer in [a question on the Emacs SX site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2461/how-can-i-simulate-an-arbitary-key-event-from-elisp). Basically, you have to put the desired sequence of keys into `unread-command-events` after converting it to the proper format. For example:

```
(let ((unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (kbd "blu RET"))))
  (ido-completing-read "Select a color: " '("yellow" "blue")))
```

Properly returns `"blue"`.

One thing to be careful about is that you have to make sure that your key sequence will definitely terminate the interactive part of the command, or else the command will continue waiting for input. One way to ensure termination is to append "C-g" to the key sequence, which will abort the command if it hasn't finished by the time it gets to the end of the key sequence. If the command does finish, then any unused input will be discarded when the let-binding goes out of scope, so the C-g event will not signal an error. So a more proper test might be:

```
;; Runs successfully
(condition-case nil
    (let ((unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (kbd "blu RET C-g"))))
      (ido-completing-read "Select a color: " '("yellow" "blue")))
  (quit (error "Reached end of `unread-command-events' without terminating")))

;; Throws an error
(condition-case nil
    (let ((unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence (kbd "blu C-g"))))
      (ido-completing-read "Select a color: " '("yellow" "blue")))
  (quit (error "Reached end of `unread-command-events' without terminating")))
```

An important caveat to this approach is that despite allowing you to run an interactive function completely non-interactively, it *will not work in a batch-mode emacs session*, presumably because emacs doesn't process keyboard input at all in batch mode.

Comment: You made my day!  THANKS!

Comment: Ahh, missed that this won't work in batch-mode.  What a pity!

Comment: @Geradlus_RU FYI, I have released a new implementation (linked above) that should work in batch mode as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `execute-kbd-macro` and ERT. I have a very simple implementation in [my test file](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/ivy-test.el).
The tests actually look very neat - almost as if I was pressing the keys interactively:

```cl
(ert-deftest ivy-read ()
  (should (equal
           (ivy-with '(ivy-read "pattern: " '("blue" "yellow"))
                     "C-m")
           "blue"))
  (should (equal
           (ivy-with '(ivy-read "pattern: " '("blue" "yellow"))
                     "y C-m")
           "yellow"))
  (should (equal
           (ivy-with '(ivy-read "pattern: " '("blue" "yellow"))
                     "y DEL b C-m")
           "blue"))
  (should (equal
           (ivy-with '(ivy-read "pattern: " '("blue" "yellow"))
                     "z C-m")
           "z")))
```

Comment: Looking at your implementation of `ivy-with`, it appears that your implementation requires defining a command and binding it to a key, which is workable but a bit messy if the user wants to run a test in their emacs session.

Comment: I've taken your concept of using `execute-kbd-macro` and rewritten it to be as hygienic as possible [here](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/blob/bleeding-edge/test/ido-cr%2B-test.el#L11-L69). It defines the command lexically using `cl-letf`, ensures that the command's binding won't interfere with normal key bindings, uses `cl-gensym` to guarantee no name collisions, and handles both incomplete input (e.g. not pressing RET at the end) or excess input (e.g. pressing RET twice when once is enough). The result is ... a bit longer, but shouldn't leak any part of the abstraction.

Comment: That link is now broken, but looks to be replaced by `with-simulated-input` , found at https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/with-simulated-input and on MELPA.